# Gmail API context error when i try to access to gmail inbox

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

Good afternoon,I am currently using Gmail API and i want to read mails. when i run my code i have a context error(TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'context')). My code is:

```
// authentication
const clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
const clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
const redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
const oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
const token = await readFileAsync(TOKEN_PATH);
oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);

// Access the gmail via API
const response = await gmailListMessagesAsync({
auth: oauth2Client,
userId: "me",
maxResults: 1, 
// Only get the recent email - 'maxResults' parameter
});
// display the result
console.log(response);

// Get the message id which we will need to retreive tha actual message next.
const newestMessageId = res["data"]["messages"][0]["id"];

// Retreive the actual message using the message id
response = await gmailGetMessagesAsync({
  auth: oauth2Client,
  userId: "me",
  id: newestMessageId,  
});
//Then we will need to decode the base64 encoded message.
let body_content = JSON.stringify(res.data.payload.body.data);
let data, buff;
        data = body_content;
        buff = new Buffer.from(data, "base64");
        mailBody = buff.toString();
        // display the result
        console.log(mailBody);
```

Comment: Are you using gmail sdk fro node JS ?

Comment: I am using Gmail API for Node js. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api

Comment: can you please share the logic of this function gmailGetMessagesAsync

Comment: Thanks! it's fixed! I had to install a previous version of google API!